# .Net Blazor MAUI Hybrid - Cookie Authentication

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

Im doing a proof of concept of a .Net Blazor MAUI Hybrid app which uses the **BlazorWebView** component. We have an existing database with our own Authentication using EF UserManager users that Im using to test against.
We are not using any auth providers like Google, Facebook or Microsoft.

My solution has 2 projects in solution:

- Api project - will have all the API calls including Authentication (login, Logout etc..)
- .Net Blazor MAUI Hybrid app project.

Is it possible to do Cookie authentication using a BlazorWebView component?

How does the Native app deal with cookies etc.. within the BlazorWebView

I have started looking at custom **AuthenticationStateProvider** but Im not sure if thats the correct route ?

Will I have cross domain issues if Cookie authentication is in the API project and App is in its own project?

I think it should be possible but I cant find any implementation examples online.

Comment: `BlazorWebView` is based on `Webview`.  Do you want to implement such a feature: [Web authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) ?